# string matching with re in python

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I would like to separate numbers from string in python using `re` module, but I couldn't.

I tried the following code:

```
import re
t='0.555/0.980/2.563'
r=re.search( (".*")+re.escape('/'),t).group()
print "first number " ,r
```

I got this:

```
0.555/0.980/
```

How could I get the first and last numbers?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `t.split("/")`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like this:

```
result = re.match(r'(\d*\.?\d+)/.+/(\d*\.?\d+)', '0.555/0.980/2.563')
```

Then `result.group(1)` and `result.group(2)` will give you what you want. The way to see this is that the `()` define the specific groups you want. The stuff in the `()` tells you what sort of pattern you want - in this case, the regex is tuned to capture all decimal numbers that appear there.

But @zondo is right: you can get much better behaviour with `result = t.split('/')`. Then `result[0]` and `result[-1]` will give you the first and last splits accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` to split numbers provided that your string format remains same.

```
import re

dataString = "0.555/0.980/2.563"

numbers = [float(n) for n in  re.split("/", dataString, re.DOTALL)]

print(numbers)
```

This will extract numbers in array

```
[0.555, 0.98, 2.563]
```

If you have to print each number separately, simply iterate over list.

```
for n in numbers:
    print(n)
```

You'll get:

```
0.555
0.98 
2.563
```